# Tinted green picture when connecting Dell Inspiron 1525 to a TV via HDMI

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 1525
Intel GMA x3100 graphics
Intel 965 chipset

The built-in monitor works fine, but when I try to connect it to my Toshiba 32WL48E LCD TV via the HDMI port, I get a green tinted picture.

The same laptop worked fine with the same TV with Windows (I reformatted and installed Ubuntu 11.04 now, so no windows left).

I checked the TV and the settings are fine, as is the HDMI cable, so the problem must exist in the software settings.

Anyone know how to resolve this issue so the picture on the HDMI TV looks normal?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)